# Basic transformer calculating loss in python

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

## To calculate the loss, we need to pass in a label:

```
model_inputs = tokenizer(input_str, return_tensors="pt")

labels = ['NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE']
model_inputs['labels'] = torch.tensor([1])

model_outputs = model(**model_inputs)
```

Can anyone explain what does the 3rd line of code does?

Answer (score 0):

In the generic transformer classes, the model internally calculates the cross entropy loss when provided with labels, which is how the model usually trains. You can refer to how the classes are written with [Andrej Karpathy's simplistic code for GPT-based models.](https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT/blob/eba36e84649f3c6d840a93092cb779a260544d08/model.py#L184C17-L184C17). Such methods are traditionally followed with several other tasks such as classification, etc.

Back to what the third line does, its trying to add label to the inputs provided to the model so that it can generate a loss based on that, which you can get using model_outputs.loss.

When you look at the class for [Huggingface models outputs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.CausalLMOutput.loss)(The usual import pattern), you ll find this particular loss check done when the labels are provided.

Comment: I am using this model https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/distilbert#transformers.DistilBertForSequenceClassification.forward.labels
May I enquire if the argument for the label is the ground truth tensor in this case [1]

Comment: Yes, the labels are the ground truth tensors in your case.